# "Failed to delete" message when deleting files from SD card

Tags: notifications, sd-card, 5.1-lollipop

I use smartphone with Android version 5.1.1 Whenever I try to delete files (videos, images, ebooks, etc) from my SD card I get the "Failed to delete" message. I looked for the solution to the problem online but didn't find the matching. What I tried was I unmounted my SD card and mounted it to my PC. Then I ran cmd as administrator and tried these commands in order:

```
diskpart 
list disk
select disk 1 (which pointed to my SD card)
attribut disk clear readonly
```

It didn't work out.

What do you suggest to do?

Comment: It happened to me atleast 2 or 3 times alraeady. I did not manage to recover it since it's in readonly. If DISPART did not cut it, there's no other way I think.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very common problem for less reputed SD cards. It can be fixed by doing a full format on the SD card. (Not a quick format because it doesn't check for bad sectors or data redundancy errors). Don't forget to keep a backup before formatting.